# Unable to refer to Sheet row. Only return row data of current sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and coding in general. I am struggling with this bit of code where I would like to copy the data in row A in sheet "System 1" and use it in my validation list. However, with this current bit of code, it seems that I am getting the row data from my current sheet and not from sheet "System 1"

What am I doing wrong here? What's the best practice when referring to other sheets to optimise the speed sheet of excel?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim range1 As Range, rng As Range
Set Sheet = Sheets("System 1")

Set range1 = Sheets("System 1").Range("A1:BB1")
Set rng = Range("M2")

With rng.Validation
     .Delete 'delete previous validation
     .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
     Formula1:="='" & Name & "'!" & .range1.Address
End With
```

Comment: What is `Name`? should that be `.Name` inside your with block?

Comment: Is this code located on the sheet where you want to track `SelectionChange`? Also, are you sure you are looking for a `SelectionChange` and not a cell value being changed?

Comment: Maybe you should give more detail about what you would like to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you a good start. Fix and adjust to your needs. Study the **customize sections** of the code carefully. The `WSChange` should work perfectly except maybe there is something weird about those public variables (you can always put them into the procedure ... and the events are ... I don't get them, but I will soon enough.

You cannot use a range from a different worksheet to use it as a validation range (similar to conditional formatting, that is for Excel 2003), so you have to define a name to use as a range.

This one goes into a **module**. I just couldn't see it in the worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Public strMain As String
Public Const cStrValList As String = "ValList" 'Validation List Name

Sub WSChange()

'-- Customize BEGIN --------------------
  'Name of the main worksheet containing the validation RANGE.
'***  The worksheet should be defined by name so that this script can be run ***
'***  from other worksheets (Do NOT use the Activesheet, if not necessary).  ***                                          ***
  Const cStrMain As String = "Main" 'If "" then Activesheet is used.
  'Name of the worksheet containing the validation LIST.
  Const cStrSys As String = "System 1"
'***  The next two constants should be defined as first cell ranges, so when ***
'***  adding new data, the last cell could be calculated again and the data  ***                                          ***
'***  wouldn't be 'out of bounds' (outside the range(s)).
  'Validation RANGE Address. Can be range or first cell range address.
  Const cStrMainRng As String = "$M$2" 'orig. "$M$2"
  'Validation LIST Range Address. Can be range or first cell range address.
  Const cStrSysRng As String = "$A$1" 'orig. "$A$1:$BB$1"
'-- Customize END ----------------------
  strMain = cStrMain

  Dim oWsMain As Worksheet
  Dim oRngMain As Range
  Dim oWsSys As Worksheet
  Dim oRngSys As Range
  Dim oName As Name

  Dim strMainRng As String
  Dim strMainLast As String
  Dim strSysRng As String
  Dim strSysLast As String
'---------------------------------------
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 'No error handling so far!
'---------------------------------------
'Main Worksheet
  If cStrMain <> "" Then 'When cStrMain is used as the worksheet name.
    Set oWsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrMain)
   Else 'cStrMain = "", When ActiveSheet is used instead. Not recommended.
    Set oWsMain = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  End If
  With oWsMain
    If .Range(cStrMainRng).Cells.Count <> 1 Then
      strMainRng = cStrMainRng
     Else
      'Calculate Validation Range Last Cell Address
      strMainLast = .Range(Cells(Rows.Count, _
          .Range(cStrMainRng).Column).Address).End(xlUp).Address
      'Calculate Validation Range and assign to a range variable
      strMainRng = cStrMainRng & ":" & strMainLast 'First:Last
    End If
    Set oRngMain = .Range(strMainRng) 'Validation Range
  End With
'---------------------------------------
'System Worksheet
  Set oWsSys = Worksheets(cStrSys) 'Worksheet with Validation List
  With oWsSys
    If .Range(cStrSysRng).Cells.Count <> 1 Then
      strSysRng = cStrSysRng
     Else
      'Calculate Validation Range Last Cell Address
      strSysLast = .Range(Cells(.Range(cStrSysRng).Row, _
          Columns.Count).Address).End(xlToLeft).Address
      'Calculate Validation Range and assign to a range variable
      strSysRng = cStrSysRng & ":" & strSysLast 'First:Last
    End If
    Set oRngSys = .Range(strSysRng) 'Validation List Range
  End With
'---------------------------------------
'Name
  For Each oName In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If oName.Name = cStrValList Then
      oName.Delete
      Exit For 'If found, Immediately leave the For Each Next loop.
    End If
  Next
  ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=cStrValList, RefersTo:="='" & cStrSys _
      & "'!" & strSysRng
  With oRngMain.Validation
      .Delete 'delete previous validation
      .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
          xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & cStrValList
  End With
'---------------------------------------
ProcedureExit:
  Set oRngMain = Nothing
  Set oRngSys = Nothing
  Set oWsSys = Nothing
  Set oWsMain = Nothing
Exit Sub
'---------------------------------------
ErrorHandler:
  'Handle Errors!
  MsgBox "An error has occurred.", vbInformation
GoTo ProcedureExit
'---------------------------------------
End Sub
```

And some '**eventing**', not so good, but I've run out of patience.
This actually goes into the '**System 1**' worksheet. You should maybe figure out something like that for the 'main' sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public PreviousTarget As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'MsgBox Target.Cells.Count

'-- Customize BEGIN --------------------
  Const cStr1 = "Validation List Change"
  Const cStr2 = "Values have changed"
  Const cStr3 = "Previous Value"
  Const cStr4 = "Current Value"
'-- Customize END ----------------------

  Dim str1 As String

'Values in the NAMED RANGE (cStrValList)
  'Only if a cell in the named range has been 'addressed' i.e. a cell is
  'selected and you start typing or you click in the fomula bar, and then
  'enter is pressed, this will run which still doesn't mean the value has
  'been changed i.e. the same value has been written again... If the escape
  'key is used it doesn't run.
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range(cStrValList)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
      WSChange
      MsgBox "Cannot handle multiple cells, yet."
     Else
      'Check if the value has changed.
      If PreviousTarget <> Target.Value Then  'The value has changed.
        WSChange
        str1 = cStr1 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & cStr2 & ":" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "'" & _
            Target.Address & "' " & cStr3 & " = '"
        str1 = str1 & PreviousTarget & "'" & vbCrLf & "'" & Target.Address
        str1 = str1 & "' " & cStr4 & " = '" & Target.Value & "'."
        MsgBox str1, vbInformation
       Else 'The value has not changed.
      End If
    End If
   Else 'The cell range is out of bounds.
  End If

'Values in the NAMED RANGE ROW outside the NAMED RANGE (cStrValList9
  Dim strOutside As String
  'Here comes some bad coding.
  strOutside = Range(cStrValList).Address
  strOutside = Split(strOutside, ":")(1)
  strOutside = Range(strOutside).Offset(0, 1).Address
  strOutside = strOutside & ":" _
      & Cells(Range(strOutside).Row, Columns.Count).Address
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range(strOutside)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
      WSChange
      MsgBox "Cannot handle multiple cells, yet."
     Else
      If PreviousTarget <> Target.Value Then 'The value has changed.
        If strMain <> "" Then
          WSChange
         Else
          MsgBox "You have to define a worksheet by name under 'cStrMain'."
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  'This gets the 'previous' Target value. This is gold concerning the speed of
  'execution. It's a MUST REMEMBER.
  PreviousTarget = Target.Value
End Sub

Sub vallister()
  MsgBox Range(cStrValList).Address
End Sub
Sub sdaf()
End Sub
```